# No indication when users tab of tag page is selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-wiki

This is just purely aesthetics but in the spirit of consistency in the site, I'm reporting this.

If you navigate to the "topusers" page for a tag's wiki page (labeled "users"), the "tab" up top does not have the visual indicator that the "users" page is being viewed.  All other pages does have the indicator.  Should be an easy fix right?

e.g.,

> [C# Info Page:
>
>   [image: C# Info Page]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info)

> [C# Users Page:
>
>   [image: C# Users Page]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/topusers)

Comment: Confirmed. Nice catch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed, renaming this tab has resulted in so many bugs, thanks for reported - will be deployed today.